# Able to Encrypt, but not able to decrypt using Dart Encrypt Package

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, encryption, aes

I am saving the user password in cipher text
using

```
Future<String> _encryptPassword(String password, Uint8List key) async {
  final keyUint8List = key.sublist(0, 32); 
  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(Key(keyUint8List), mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'));

  final encryptedPassword = encrypter.encrypt(password, iv: iv);

  return base64Encode(encryptedPassword.bytes);
}
```

and I am saving it firestore database

No if i try to fetch it

I am calling

```
 Future<List<String>?> decryptPasswords(
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> passwordDataList, Uint8List aesKey) async {
    try {
      final List<String> decryptedPasswords = [];

      for (final passwordData in passwordDataList) {
        final encryptedPassword = passwordData['encrypted_password'];

        if (aesKey != null) {
          final keyUint8List = aesKey.sublist(0, 32);
          final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

          final encrypter = Encrypter(
              AES(Key(keyUint8List), mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'));

          final encryptedBytes = base64Decode(encryptedPassword);
          final decryptedBytes = encrypter.decryptBytes(Encrypted(encryptedBytes), iv: iv);

          final decryptedPassword = utf8.decode(decryptedBytes);

          decryptedPasswords.add(decryptedPassword);
        }
      }

      return decryptedPasswords;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error decrypting passwords: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

But its giving
I/flutter (14298): Error decrypting passwords: Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block
at this point

```
          final decryptedBytes = encrypter.decryptBytes(Encrypted(encryptedBytes), iv: iv);
```

I am trying to debug, I have make sure that the aes key and password is same.
Please tell if more data is required, I can give it

Comment: [`IV.fromLength(int length)`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/IV/IV.fromLength.html) generates a *random* IV, which is why in your code encryption and decryption use different IVs. This results (for CBC) in a corruption of the first block during decryption. Fix: Use the IV of the encryption for decryption. It is correct to generate a random IV during encryption. This IV is to be passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext, typically concatenated (the IV is not a secret).

Comment: Yes, I read about it now, its working, i am still starting on this, that's why I missed it.
Thanks so much @Topaco

Comment: If anyone needs a   SimpleEncryptor object that solves this problem.. However, it is downgraded encryption for nonsensitive info and not for super secret stuff.  I ended up using the user password as the iv.  You can find it in the next few days in the utils folder here.
https://github.com/bksubhuti/tipitaka-pali-reader/tree/master/lib/utils